# Удалить определенный экзепляр класса из ObservableCollection

Tags: wpf, mvvm, usercontrol, wpf-commands

Добрый день подскажите что делать и куда нужно смотреть, чтобы изменить коллекцию. Описана Model называется Cars у неё внутри реализованы команды, и они отлично отрабатывают.

```
public ICommand EditCommand { get; set; }
public ICommand SaveCommand { get; set; }
```

Вынос всей логики работы был необходим так как я работаю с отдельным UserControl. В UserControl есть кнопки(команды) которые должны быть независимы друг от друга.

```
<ListView x:Name="SkLb" ItemsSource="{Binding Cars}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
                <ListView.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <VirtualizingStackPanel IsItemsHost="True" Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemsPanel>
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <local:UCCarsView Padding="10"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
```

View - local:UCCarsView использует Model Cars для отображения и биндинга свойств(для одной единицы), а VMCars через ListView отображает всю коллекцию.
Но нужна ещё одна команда которую я запихнуть не могу(или могу) внутри Cars(Model) а именно удаление, Если я её также привязываю внутри модели, элемент из базы я могу удалить но коллекцию обновить не могу. Как правильно написать удаление, чтобы коллекцию мог контролировать.
Именно в VMCars происходит работа со всей коллекцией

```
public VMCars ()
{
            Cars= new ObservableCollection<Cars>();
......
......
......
}
```

Делал так, в команду в моей VMCars заходит, но получить в каком конкретном UC была нажата эта кнопка не могу,не удаётся получить от ListView свойство SelectedItem, он срабатывает только когда кликаешь непосредственно по элементу. Если кликнуть по кнопке внутри UC возвращает null.

```
<Button Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type ListView}}, Path=DataContext.DeleteCommand}" >  </Button>
```

Надеюсь объяснил адекватно, если что-то непонятно уточняйте. Помогите мне решить эту делему

Comment: Каша какая то. У вас напротив в каждом пункте UCCarsView кнопки для редактирования/удаления текущего пункта? Так заведите CarViewModel и пусть будет  new ObservableCollection<CarViewModel> и внутри CarViewModel вы сможете обработать нажатие кнопки для этого Car. Или же добавьте в код приведенного биндинга к button CommandParameter={Binding}

Comment: Согласен, очень тяжело понять, что я объяснил. Голова не соображает.У меня каждой UC есть свой набор кнопок и полей, которые повторяются в каждом UC и вся работа с логикой работы вынесена в Model. А сама коллекция лежит как раз таки в CarsViewModel там формируется коллекция Cars и отдаётся в ListView для бинда. 
CarViewModel у меня выполняет Model, там находится вся что связано с логикой работы одного UC. 
А я насколько понимаю удаление должно быть как раз в CarsViewModel так как я по-другому удалить не смогу из коллекции. А что вы имеете в виду под CommandParameter={Binding} ?

Comment: 1 CarViewModel оборачивает Car (1 машина) и позволяет помимо проброса значений модели к View еще добавить логику для UI - например IsSelected или команды Edit/SaveCommand. В этом случае событие придет внутрь этого VM и нужно будет уведомить рутовую vm "меня удалил, удали меня из своей коллекции". Например событие Deleted или ссылка на рутовую vm. 2 Забиндить все кнопки в списке на команду рутовой vm (вот как вы сделали в примере). Но у вас SelectedItem пуст, ведь выделения не происходит. А значит вы должны добавить в команду CommandParameter={Binding} и в обработчик прилетит нужный car

Comment: Огромное вам спасибо за разъяснения. Я понял что как и куда уходит. SelectedItem всё равно осталось пустым, но перегрузив DeleteCommand = new RelayCommand<object>(Delete); на получения объекта я всё-таки получил то что нужно.